# Segmentation fault within do_crypt()

Tags: c

This is my code but when I run it, it gives me a segmentation fault in the function do_crypt(). When I try to print all the keys in the function it will only print out a few and I don't know why because if I print all the keys before calling do_crypt it will print them without any issues.

Any advice in fixing this would be lovely!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>


#define MAX_LINE_NUM 25143
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 80
#define MAX_WORDS 25143
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 30

char words[MAX_WORDS][MAX_WORD_LEN];
unsigned char output[] = "";

void read_KeyFile(int *line_counter, char *KeyFilename, char arr[MAX_LINE_NUM][MAX_LINE_LEN]){
    FILE *fptr;
    char read_line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_NUM];
    const char delim[] = " \n";
    int buff_line_num = 0;
    int word_counter = 0;
    char *token;

    fptr = fopen(KeyFilename, "r");
    while(fgets(read_line, MAX_LINE_LEN, fptr) != NULL){
        strncpy(arr[*line_counter], read_line, MAX_LINE_LEN);
        *line_counter = *line_counter + 1;
    }
    fclose(fptr);

    for (int i = 0; i<*line_counter; i++){
        strncpy(buffer, arr[buff_line_num], MAX_LINE_LEN);
        token = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while(token != NULL){
            strncpy(words[word_counter], token, MAX_WORD_LEN);
            word_counter = word_counter + 1;

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        buff_line_num++;
    }
}

int do_crypt(char plaintext[], char ciphertext[], unsigned char tempKey[], unsigned char output[], int do_encrypt){

    unsigned char inbuf[1024], outbuf[1024 + EVP_MAX_BLOCK_LENGTH];
    int inlen, outlen;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

    unsigned char iv[] = "aabbccddeeff00998877665544332211";
    unsigned char key[] = "";
    strcpy(key, tempKey);
    int len = strlen(key);
    
    if (len < 16){
        for (int i=0; i<(16-len)+1; i++){
            strcat(key, "#");
        }
    }

    FILE *in;
    in = fopen("Input.txt", "r");
    FILE *out;
    out = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, NULL, NULL, do_encrypt);
    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_key_length(&ctx) == 16);
    OPENSSL_assert(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length(&ctx) == 16);

    EVP_CipherInit_ex(&ctx, NULL, NULL, key, iv, do_encrypt);

    for(;;) {
        inlen = fread(inbuf, 1, 1024, in);
        if(inlen <= 0) break;
        if(!EVP_CipherUpdate(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen, inbuf, inlen)){
            /* Error */
            EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
            return 0;
        }
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
        strcpy(output, outbuf);
    }
    if(!EVP_CipherFinal_ex(&ctx, outbuf, &outlen)){
        /* Error */
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        return 0;
    }
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, outlen, out);
    strcpy(output, outbuf);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);


    return 1;

}

void toHexConverter(unsigned char output[], int i, unsigned char tempKey[17]){
    char hex[100];
    for (int j=0, k=0; j<strlen(output); ++j, k +=2){
        sprintf(hex + k, "%02x", output[j] & 0xff);
    }
    strcpy(output, hex);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    char plaintext[] = "This is a top secret.";
    unsigned char ciphertext[] = "764aa26b55a4da654df6b19e4bce00f4ed05e09346fb0e762583cb7da2ac93a2";
    char hexCompare[] = "";
    

    int line_counter = 0;
    char *KeyFilename = NULL;
    char lines[MAX_LINE_NUM][MAX_LINE_LEN];    
    unsigned char tempKey[] = "";
    int do_encrypt = 1;
    
    KeyFilename = argv[1];
    
    read_KeyFile(&line_counter, KeyFilename, lines);
    
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_WORDS; i++){
        // printf("%s\n", words[i]);
        strcpy(tempKey, words[i]);
        do_crypt(plaintext, ciphertext, tempKey, output, do_encrypt);
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=MAX_WORDS; i++)` looks suspicious. It could break the array, but there is code you don't show. Anyway `unsigned char tempKey[17]` looks tight. Don't be mean with the string sizes: try `unsigned char tempKey[100]`.

Comment: I edited the question and posted my entire code

Comment: `i<=MAX_WORDS`  should be `i<MAX_WORDS`. An array in C is indexed from `0` to `[length-1]`. Watch out for other end tests too such as `i<(16-len)+1` although I don't know that's a fault.

Comment: It is i<MAX_WORDS and still gives seg fault

Comment: I suggest you deploy the debugger to find out where the fault occurs.